# Linux(Ubuntu 12) настройка Dhcp сервера для двух сетевых карт?

Tags: linux

Есть сервер на Ubuntu, на нем есть три сетевые карты:

1. eth0 - внешняя сеть(интернет);
2. eth1 локальная сеть,

Как лучше настроить третью карту как запасной линк?

Answer (score 1):

Можно объединить две карточки используя bridge-utils